# Discrete math and integer solutions problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do we find the number of nonnegative integer solutions of the inequality:

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 < 10\text{ ?}$$

Answer is $5005$, can someone elaborate and show me the steps required to solve this discrete math problem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/number-of-nonnegative-integral-solutions-of-x-1-x-2-cdots-x-k-n?rq=1

Comment: @FlybyNight in the original post without edit are $x_6$ variables

Comment: @rlartiga Thanks

Comment: @FlybyNight : It looked like a typo to me: x+6 appeared where x_6 was intended.  The two keys are adjacent on keyboards in the USA.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The "typo" had been made by someone that edited the OP.

Comment: So how would we go about solving this?

Comment: The first thing I notice about this is that $5005$ is a binomial coefficient: $\dbinom{15}6 = 5005$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I [solved it](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/809349/85343) in another post.

Answer (score 3):

We have $9$ identical candies, and there are $6$ kids wanting candy. How many ways are there to distribute $9$ **or fewer** candies between the $6$ kids?

Equivalently, imagine that there is a $7$-th kid who will get any lefover candies. The number of ways to give out $9$ or fewer candies to $6$ kids, with some possibly getting $0$ candies, is the number of ways to distribute $9$ candies among $7$ kids.

This is a standard Stars and Bars problem that you are likely familiar with, perhaps in the less sweet form of counting the solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_7=9$.

Comment: Please go into more detail about the 7th kid, why are we all of a sudden adding another x to the equation?

Comment: Because counting the solutions of the inequality $x_1+\cdots +x_6\le 9$ is the same as counting the solutions of the equality $x_1+\cdots +x_6+x_7=9$. The solutions with $x_7=0$ give us the solutions of $x_1+\cdots +c_6=9$, the solutions with $x_7=1$ give us the solutions with $x_1+\cdots +x_6=8$, and so on.

Comment: FACEPALM -_-...... Sorry for asking the obvious. I must have been over thinking this.

Comment: No problem, it is important to gain clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Imagine the $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_6$ as letter boxes that you have to put letters into.

Let $x_7$ be a bin, where the letters you post don't count for anything.

You have nine letters to post and seven boxes to post them in.

If you put all nine in $x_7$ then $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6=0$.

If you put eight in $x_7$ then $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6=1$.

If you put seven in $x_7$ then $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6=2$.

*How many ways are there of posting nine letters in seven boxes, when order doesn't matter?*

Comment: Why is there x7 please explain, I am stuck on that

Comment: @Ash Instead of counting all of the cases separately, you can include an $x_7$. You can think of the $x_7$ as a bin, or as your pocket. If you have $x_1+\cdots+x_6=0$ then you have not posted a single letter into any of the postboxes $x_1,\ldots,x_6$; they are all in your pocket. If $x_1+\cdots+x_6=1$ then you have posted a single letter; all-but-one are in your pocket. You can count all cases, i.e. $=0$, $=1$, $=2$, etc, by including your pocket in the counting. You have nine letters to post (or not post)

Answer (score 0):

The number of solutions is the sum of the solutions of the equations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i=j,j=0,\ldots,9$$

The number of solutions of each one is $\binom{j+6-1}{6-1}$ (according with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/number-of-nonnegative-integral-solutions-of-x-1-x-2-cdots-x-k-n?rq=1)) so the total is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^9 \binom{j+5}{5} $$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we wanted to know the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = k$.  This is equivalent to the combinatorics question "How many ways are there to distribute $k$ indistinguishable balls into $n$ distinguishable boxes?".  It is a well-known combinatorics [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) that the answer to this question is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Therefore, the total number of solutions is going to have to take into account the number of possibilities for $0$ balls, $1$ ball, and so forth up to $9$.  Thus, the following expression gives us what we want:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^9 \binom{k + 5}{k}$$